# Problems reading first line from file after 'getline'

Tags: c++, getline

After inputting `getline`, the first row of numbers in my input file are ignored and the program starts at the second line until the end.

Here's the code:

```
while (!file.eof())
{
    getline(file, lineBuffer);
    if(lineBuffer.length()==0)
    {
        continue; //ignore empty lines
    }
    else 
    {
       // file.open("test.txt");
        while (file >> A >> B >> N)
        {

            for(int count=1; count<=N; count++)
            {
                if(count%A == 0 && count%B == 0) { cout << "FB "; }

                else if(count%A == 0) { cout << "F "; }

                else if(count%B == 0) { cout << "B "; }

                else { cout << count << " "; }

            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The input file contains 3 rows of integers and only the second line and third like are processed. I've looked this up extensively, but no one has mentioned a case similar to mine. Usually they deal with people trying to get user input after a `getline` function. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked `linebuffer` data ? and what is in `test.txt`?

Comment: Can you show a sample input file?

Comment: There're a thousand questions about this :-(. You must attempt to get some data before testing for `eof()`. When you use `getline`, check the result to see if it succeeded. Your attempt to ignore empty lines also throws away the `lineBuffer` content where you found `lineBuffer.length() != 0`... that contains the first set of A, B, N results you're missing.  You could just leave off everything outside the `while (file >> A...)` loop and it would start working as you presumably want (you haven't said what you expect, but I assume it's to process that first row).

Comment: By the way, don't use `while (!file.eof())`. Instead do as you do in your other loop: `while (std::getline(...))`

Answer (score 2):

`getline(file, lineBuffer)` reads a line from `file` and stores it in `lineBuffer`. If you want to use it, you should then process `lineBuffer` instead of reading from `file` (where the first line will already be skipped). To make it work, simply remove all code outside of the inner `while`. This will read from the file 3 numbers at a time, stopping when extracting one of them fails.

Comment: Firstly, I forgot to mention that this is a coding challenge on CodeEval that I was attempting. I was under the impression that this test case code was unavoidable and had to be in there, but I believe it's only optional... Here is the verbiage from the code input window from the submission page:

/*Sample code to read in test cases:
ifstream file;
file.open(argv[1])
while (!file.eof()) 
   {
       getline(file, lineBuffer);
       if (lineBuffer.length() == 0)
           continue; //ignore all empty lines
       else 
       {
           //do something here
       }
}*/

Comment: @StephenPaul If you use that code template, you would then process `lineBuffer` instead of reading more numbers from `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the above code real or is it an example?

If it is real, you don't need to skip th eempty lines. The operator>> will skip the whitespaces for you.

The following code without any lineskipping performs just the same reading of "A B N" lines:

```
// outer loop is not needed, either remove it, or include error checking
// while (!file.eof() && !file.fail())
{
    while (file >> A >> B >> N)
    {
        for(int count=1; count<=N; count++)
        {

            if(count%A == 0 && count%B == 0) { cout << "FB "; }
....
```

If for some reason you cannot remove the getline at all, remember that getline reads the line ALWAYS (well, unless the streampointer reached its end). This means that your code skips the empty lines, then reads first nonempty line, notices that the line is not empty and breaks the loop. Note that it **has read the line**, hence, your first-line-of-data now is in the **linebuffer**, and not in the stream anymore. Now you have to either **unget** the whole line (if your stream supports it) or **rewind the stream by the line's length** (if your stream supports it) or - **just read the data from the line** - for example using **istringstream** class.

In general, mixing getline and operator>> is doable but tricky, (especially when you first read via >> and then want to skip a 1 or 2 lines), as they behave a little differently in terms of buffering and whitespace-handling. If you really want that, search for this subject - there are lots of examples how to sync them.

Comment: Hint to OP: to mix them, you typically continue to read lines into a string using getline, then use that string to initialise an `istringstream` from which you parse out your per-line values....

Comment: I would drop the `while(!file.eof())`. The first time you enter it is always true. The second time, if the read failed for something other than end-of-file, you have an infinite loop.